# Override SWING setText() method for entire project

Tags: java, swing, settext

I would like to be able to override the setText() for textField objects. 
I know that one can do this by creating a new class that implements the textField and then creating instances of that class.
But I would like to directly modify the method so that all instances of textField in the complete project have this overriden method by default. This would be similar to the UIManager.put() method that allows you, for example to have a specific font for all textFields without having to code it every time.
Is this possible?

Comment: `I would like to be able to override the setText() for textField objects` - to do what? If we know the requirement, not your attempted solution, maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I believe you need to extend JTextField as a new class. Then override the setText() method. You'll have to use this new text field class going forward. That is how overriding works.

Comment: Thanks alot for your replies.
So I would like setText() to set the caret back to zero at the end of the method. 
I know about extending methods. I don't want to do it because I am already  deep in the project and changing all the instances of JTextField seems like it will be highly tedious.